# Viewpager is not visible inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a BottomNavigation bar in main activity. Which has 5 items.

Here is the getitem method for that bottomnavigation

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new ChatRoomPage();
            case 1:
                return new TopicPage();
            case 2:
                return new TopicPage();
            case 3:
                return new Leaderboard();
            case 4:
                return new Stats();
        }
        return new ChatRoomPage();
    }
```

I have added `TopicPage()` for testing.

So topic page is a fragment with tab layout. And that fragment shows three other fragments using tab view.

`TopicPage()` in case 2 is working fine.

But in case 3 fragment `TopicPage()` is showing. It's also calling the three fragments in tab layout (Getting message in log). But not visible in ViewPager. And the underline on tablayout is not sliding from one tab to another tab with animaton. I have to slide it manually.

And,

When I add a single fragment like `Stats()` or `Leaderboard()` it works.

Screenshot
[image: ss]

Topic Page onCreateview

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topic_page, container, false);
    tabLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.tab);
    pager = v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    pager.setAdapter(new TopicPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    return v;
}
```

So I don't know why I am getting this problem...

Need Help :(

Comment: So you have nested ViewPagers?

Comment: @elmorabea yeah

Comment: If user is viewing case 1 or case 2 ie(Topic Page) how the user will return to main Tab Layout, ie initial/parent layout , do u have the screenshots?

Comment: screenshot.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eM4OWGGS7Ly3cp600Wvz5NPfJk7z6rwY/view?usp=sharing @lib4

Comment: Would you mind trying this. When showing Fragments inside another Fragment, use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager()

Initialize your pageAdapter this way:

pageAdapter = new FragmentHomeAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), pageList);

Comment: @lib4 Thank you so much!!! that worked. You can add it in answer below..

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. I added it as answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 1):

Override a method in `TopicPage()` fragment called `setUserVisibilityHint()`
and in that method after the return statement ...write 
`if(getActivity()!=null) { viewPager.setAdapter(....youradapter); }` I think it will work. First initialize the adapter of viewPager then set the adapter.....Let me know if it works..

Comment: Tried. But it's not working. Case 1 topic page is also not showing after doing it.. The code    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(getActivity()!=null) { pager.setAdapter(new TopicPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager())); }
    }

Comment: @NoobCoder did you get solution or should I paste entire code for you ?

Comment: I'm still facing this issue. @nihal_softy

Comment: @NoobCoder As per my understanding you want to use view pager inside fragment ?. Right ?

Comment: Yeah.. Check this ss. 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eM4OWGGS7Ly3cp600Wvz5NPfJk7z6rwY/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: @NoobCoder initialize at both the places that is both in onCreateView and setUserVisibilityHint() did u do that?? set the adapter in both the overriden methods...try it..

Comment: Great .. Allow me couple of minutes.. Adding Answer over here

Answer (score 1):

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

**PagerAdapter For Fragment**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

**FirstFragment**

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
}
```

}